# Replace json array with another, but keep the order

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an API that responds with json like this:

```
{'items':[
{'id': 1, 'quantity': 3},
{'id': 4, 'quantity': 7},
{'id': 5, 'quantity': 1}
]}
```

I've made it so on page it fetches this API every 15 seconds, however there's a problem that every time it has a different order in array (if in example item with id=1 is on first place, it may be on last next time). Because of that blocks on page change their order too. I've tried to counter it like this:

```
   for (var i in response.items) {
                   let current_item = response.items[i];
                   for (var i2 in original_items.items) {
                       if (original_items.items[i2].id === current_item.id) {
                           original_items.items[i2] = current_item;
                       }
                   }
               }
```

But it doesn't work this way. Sorting them by id is not a viable option aswell

Comment: Will existing items in the array ever be removed? If so, what would you want to happen to that item in `original_items` then?

Comment: you can just sort items so that you don't need to check with previous items as previous items will also be sorted

Comment: post your api code to.

Comment: Why is "Sorting them by id is not a viable option as well" not an option?!? I believe this is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: CertainPerformance if its not in a new array anymore, then it should be removed from result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by ID should be quite viable. Whenever a response comes back (including the response to the initial request), sort the array of objects:

```
response.items.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Comment: the original object may not be sorted asc or desc right? and question is to be sorted in original object order, like 1, 4, 5

Comment: That's correct AbbasEbadian, i want to keep the very original order

Comment: @Andrew Since the sort order sounds unspecified, simply sort *all* API responses, including the original response.

Comment: In that case you can quickly clone it first by doing something like `let sortedItems=response.items.slice().sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)`. And then work with `sortedItems`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i guess that would be the most logical way, thanks